# AngularJS constantly watch on text input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, textwatcher

I am wondering if it is posible to constantly watching the text input, like typing a string and then run a function.

I would use it for html game, that if you like type the word pause on a random moment you pause the game.

Is this possible to make? or are there any easy sample scripts? That would help me alot!
Thanks!

Comment: you can take use of `watch` on scope variable

Comment: but how can I constantly watch for a specific string or string type that has some specific type of characters? Is it smart to save every new character in a new variable and check if it contains?

Comment: get better idea from http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2658-using-scope-watch-to-watch-functions-in-angularjs.htm

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an input with an `ng-model="myTextParam"` on it. You can write in your controller the following:

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return $scope.myTextParam; }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal === "string test") {
       //do whatever
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11511/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $scope.$watch() to run a specific function each time a scope variable changes. You can then check if your string is equal to 'pause'.

```
$scope.$watch('typeModel', function(newVal, oldVal){
    if(newVal.toLowerCase() === 'pause'){
        alert('Pause!');
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/13834/

**Update**
You can use tricks to hide your input, and making sure it doesn't lose focus.

This css makes sure your html body takes up all the available space:

```
html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

You can register a clickhandler on the body to make sure you always have focus on the input:

```
document.body.onclick = function(event){        
    document.getElementById('input_field').focus();
}
```

The `autofocus` part makes sure the input field gets focus on page load:

```
<input id="input_field" type="text" ng-model="typeModel" autofocus>
```

And you can do some css trick to hide your input (not the best example here, but just for demonstration purposes):

```
input {
    opacity: 0.01;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/13847/

Comment: Yeah that should work for an input field, but how can it work on the whole page, or on a specific element?

Comment: @RobinTimman You can use tricks like hiding your text input, and making sure it doesn't lose focus. I can update my answer.